# Why does clicking on a brand checkbox in Django and Ajax result in displaying another HTML page?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to filter products by brand name through checkboxes using django, ajax jquery, but while clicking on the checkbox I am having another products html page within the running html page including all the products. But while printing in console, i can see that unique brand name is being selected while checking a checkbox field.

Views.py

````
def list_products(request):
    ordering = request.GET.get('ordering', "")
    search = request.GET.get('search', "")
    brands = set(Product.objects.values_list('brand', flat=True))
    colors = Product.objects.values_list('color', flat=True).distinct()

    selected_brands = request.GET.getlist('brand')
    selected_colors = request.GET.getlist('color')

    filtered_products = Product.objects.all()

    if selected_brands:
        filtered_products = filtered_products.filter(brand__in=selected_brands)

    if search:
        filtered_products = filtered_products.filter(Q(title__icontains=search) | Q(brand__icontains=search))

    if ordering:
        filtered_products = filtered_products.order_by(ordering)

    context = {
        'brands': brands,
        'colors': colors,
        'selected_brands': selected_brands,
        'selected_colors': selected_colors,
        'products': filtered_products,
    }

    return render(request, "products/listproducts.html", context)```
````

HTML Code block

```
<div class="bg-light p-4 mb-30">
                    <form id="filter-form" method="GET" action="{% url 'products:list_products' %}">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-3">
                            <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="brand-all">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="brand-all">All Brands</label>
                        </div>
                        {% for brand in brands %}
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-3">
                            <input class="custom-control-input brand-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="brand-{{ brand }}" name="brand" value="{{ brand }}" {% if brand in selected_brands %}checked{% endif %}>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="brand-{{ brand }}">{{ brand }}</label>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </form>
                </div>
```

JavaScript Code block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("Document ready!");

    // Handle checkbox change event
    $(document).on('change', '.brand-checkbox', function() {
        // Get the selected checkbox values
        var selectedBrands = $('input[name="brand"]:checked').map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get();

        // AJAX request to update filtered products
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "{% url 'products:list_products' %}",
            data: {
                brand: selectedBrands,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                // Update the filtered products container
                $('#filtered-products').html(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

URL Pattern

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('list_products/', views.list_products, name='list_products'),
    path('details-<slug:slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
    path('listproducts/filter-<slug:slug>/', views.list_products, name='product_filter'),
    path('api/suggestionapi/', views.suggestionApi, name='suggestionapi'),
]
```

I am expecting to filter the products dynamically by brand name while checking the brand checkbox, but instead of filtering I am getting another listproducts.htlm page, inside my existing listproducts.html page.

Comment: Because rendering the whole page is the only thing your view can do: `return render...`. Split view behavior into two separate views: whole page render and ajax request endpoint. Or make POST requests with AJAX and put `if POST...` into your view and return only what you need in this case, not the whole page.